# Add tab functionality in editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am using an editable div and want to implement tab functionality in it but doesn't work.
When I used html textarea in place of editable div then works fine.
below code is for textarea thats working fine:

```
<textarea id="txt" style="height: 125px; overflow-y: scroll; resize: none">@Html.Raw(Model.data)</textarea>
```

```js
$('#txt').keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 9) {// 9 for tab key
        var start = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start) + "\t" + $(this).val().substring($(this).get(0).selectionEnd));
        $(this).get(0).selectionStart = $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = start + 1;
        return false;
    }
});
```

But when I used below editable div in place to textarea then doesn't work:

```
<div id="txt" contenteditable="true" style="text-align: justify; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <p>@Html.Raw(Model.data)</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="txt" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" style="text-align: justify; overflow-y: scroll;"/>
```

Give the div a `tabindex` to get focus.